# Django thread don't read valor updated

Tags: python, django, multithreading

In my models.py I hace a class how control the thread life:

```
class Repartidor(models.Model):
    thread_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)   

    def launch_thread(self):
        self.thread_active = True
        self.save()

    def kill_thread(self):
        self.thread_active = False
        self.save()

    def get_thread_state(self):
        if self.thread_active:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

In repartidor.py I declare the thread:

```
class RepartidorThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None):
        super(RepartidorThread, self).__init__()
        self.target = target
        self.name = name

    def run(self):
        repartidor = Repartidor.objects.get(pk=1)

        while True:
            condition = repartidor.get_thread_state()
            if condition:
                do_something()
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                pass
                time.sleep(1)
```

And launch the thread in wsgi.py

```
from printers.repartidor import RepartidorThread

thread_repartidor = RepartidorThread(name='Thread_Repartidor')
thread_repartidor.start()
```

But I have a problem, I read the condition in repartidor.py with `get_thread_state()` and it return True or False. If I change the condition through the django_admin or through my frontend, the value of the database is updated, and all my project read the new valor, except the thread, which always reads the first one.
If I stop and start the server, the thread read the new valor. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. In method run() I get the object in each iteration of the while loop:

```
 def run(self):
        while True:
            repartidor = Repartidor.objects.get(pk=1)
            condition = repartidor.get_thread_state()
            if condition:
                do_something()
                time.sleep(1)
            else:
                pass
                time.sleep(1)
```